# What's the best way to read xml in android?

Tags: java, android, xml

Hi I've an android app which uses an XML file to render its User Interface,And here is the xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<questions>
<question id="1" label="Name" type="text"></question>
<question id="2" label="Gender" type="select" options="Male,Female,Transgender"></question>
<question id="3" label="Age" type="text"></question>
<question id="4" label="city" type="select" options="Banglore,Hyderabad,Chennai"></question>
</questions>
```

I am using DOM parser to read xml and I am getting the inputstream using url.openconnection().getInputstream() method.But I want the xml file to be included in my android project folder and use it.How would I go about that ?? so what are the other ways to get the InputStream ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you place the file in your assets folder, you can use the AssetManager to get an input stream to it.